# W3CSS: centering input field

Tags: css, forms, input, width

Background: Ive done a few small websites using W3CSS, & get my knowledge from this website: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_input.asp

Right now, I am starting on a brand new website & having a bit of difficulty centering an input field. (the form doesnt work as yet, i'm just trying to get it to look right).

http://clubs.kwister.com/login

Basically, you can see TWO forms asking for an email address. The first one, is CENTERED, with the input field at 50% width.  However the actual input field where a person enters their email address is flushed to the left.

The second form, I have taken out the width:50%  but now i see an input field taking the whole width of the screen.

Is there something i am missing, to make it look somewhat presentable & have the actual input field centered, but only 40-50% of the width ?

I see from the W3 website that theres no 'width' examples and all the input fields take up 100% of the available width.

i do want white-space on both sides (I may or may not add anything later on to fill the whitespace)

PS I could do the w3-third class (responsive section), and divide the screen into thirds, however i want the form to take up more than a third of the width of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, There's an easy way to center an input field. There's a way you could center it by setting its `position: relative;` and `left: 25%;`, or you could set `text-align: center;` on the parent form. Depends on what you're after. Personally, I'd go with the relative position and left.

Hope that helps

ps. I wouldn't try to use `display: inline-block;` use `display: block; float: left;`

Comment: Ive numbered them, 1 (width: 50%; text-align: center;) - is still left-aligned. 2) (position: relative; and left: 25%;) still takes up the full width

Comment: have you set the `position: relative;` and `left: 25%;` on the actual input field? silly question, but I find it to be the culprit quite often...

Comment: I just looked at your code, the `text-align: center;` is for the form itself, I just realized that that was probably a bad piece of advice. try this: `<input style="position: relative; left: 25%;"/>

Answer (score 0):

Ive found a working solution - using INLINE BLOCK.

width: 50%; text-align: center; display: inline-block;

Number 1 of my example is working, i'll edit out the others out.

Answer (score 0):

If You are still using w3css stylings- inside the input feild add class w3-center 
This will center the input feild content.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this class on `div` and should be centered

```html
<div class="w3-display-container w3-col s4  w3-display-middle">
    your contents here.....
</div>
```